# probability involving rerolling dice

Tags: probability

The question go like the following.

You roll one 6 sided dice one time. You get the same money as the number of dots face up. But if you roll a six, you get nothing and re-roll. If your re-roll gets a six again, you reroll again and again. What is the expercted value of money get.

I guess i should go like the following

$$E(x)=\frac16+\frac26+\frac36+\frac46+\frac56+\frac16 E(x)$$

Comment: And if you go like the following, what result do you get in the end?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: i will get 3. but i am not sure if i am correct

Comment: Assume two sixes.What then? Is this included above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good job, your working is fine.

It is as if you are tossing a dice with $5$ sides since it is equally likely to get any numbet between $1$ and $5$ inclusive by symmetry.

Comment: but if i want to calculate the variance, when i go to the term which 6 face up , should it be $\frac16*(6-3)^2$ or $\frac16*(3-3)^2$

Comment: You can check that the probability that you will get $i$ dots where $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, 5\}$ would be $\frac15$. From there, you can compute the variance.