# Dice Probability for Rerolling Dice Spreadsheet Formula

Tags: probability, dice

How can I express the dice probability for rolling dice vs a target number with re-rolls?

There are a number of dice rolled to get a target number of hits.

- A "hit" is a 4, 5, or 6 on 1d6.
- Every 6 can be re-rolled to get
  another hit.
- There is a target number of hits required for success.

For example, if you rolled 4 dice with a target of 2 hits, I would expect the chance of success to be around 66%.

However, if you wanted to calculate the odds of getting 5 hits on 4 dice, you would need to know the odds of getting a 6 on any of those 4 die and then getting a 4,5,or 6 to get that additional required hit.

I have read several articles, such as [Ed Collins site](https://www.edcollins.com/math-questions.htm), but I cannot get it to work in a Google spreadsheet.

From that, I have gathered: `1 - (3/6)^4` for 4 dice and one hit.

For 4 dice with 2 hits, I tried multiplying both probabilities together: `1 - (3/6)^4 * (3/6)^4`

I also tried subtracting the total number of *not* 4,5,6 and then subtracting that from the total number of combinations and dividing the probability from that.

But that does not come out as expected either.

For re-rolling a 6, I looked at this post, but do not understand it:
[probability involving rerolling dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566170/probability-involving-rerolling-dice)

Is there a single Google formula that can represent the typical situation of rolling multiple dice vs a target number and then also the odds of re-rolling to achieve the success?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little. How do I find the standard probability first? This part is not working as expected 1 - (3/6)^4 * (3/6)^4. Do I do the method where I multiply probability? Or do I subtract total permutations from total possibilities? I'm stuck on that part first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single die, let's find the expected value for the number of hits.

You have a $\dfrac{1}{2}$ chance of not getting any hits on one die.

You have a $\dfrac{2}{6} + \dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{5}{12}$ chance of getting exactly 1 hit on one die.

You have a $\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{6^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{5}{72}$ chance of getting exactly 2 hits.

In general, for $h>0$, the probability of exactly $h$ hits is $$\dfrac{5}{2\cdot 6^h}$$

I am not going to go into the proof of this, but I will demonstrate that the total probability is preserved.

$$\sum_{h\ge 1} \dfrac{5}{2\cdot 6^h} = \dfrac{5}{12}\sum_{h\ge 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^h = \dfrac{5}{12}\cdot \dfrac{6}{5} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Plus the probability of $h=0$, which is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

So, this gives the expected value:

$$\dfrac{5}{12}\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^k = \dfrac{3}{5}$$

So, that is the expected value for the number of hits.

Continuing, let's create some notation.

Let $P(n,h)$ be the probability of rolling $n$ dice and getting exactly $h$ hits. Let $P(n,h^+)$ be the probability of rolling $n$ dice and getting at least $h$ hits.

$$P(n,h) = \sum_{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = h}\prod_{i=1}^n\begin{cases}\tfrac{1}{2}, & a_i = 0 \\ \tfrac{5}{2\cdot 6^{a_i}}, & a_i>0\end{cases}$$

Basically, you are summing over all nonnegative integer solutions to the Diophantine equation:
$$a_1+\cdots + a_n = h$$

This tells you which dice rolled hits, and the total number of hits is $h$. Then, multiply the probabilities that the chosen die scores that many hits.

This is an impractical approach. Instead, we can try to break down the probabilities.

Example:

$$P(4,2^+) = 1-P(4,0)-P(4,1) = 1-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4-\dbinom{4}{1}\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3 \approx 72\%$$

What I am doing here is for $P(4,0)$, this is the probability that not a single die rolled a hit. For $P(4,1)$, this is the probability that exactly one die rolled exactly one hit.

$$P(4,5^+) = 1-P(4,0)-P(4,1)-P(4,2)-P(4,3)-P(4,4)$$

This is a bit trickier to calculate.

$$\begin{align*}P(4,4) & = \dbinom{4}{1}P(1,4)P(3,0)+\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}P(1,3)P(1,1)P(2,0)+\dbinom{4}{2}P(1,2)^2P(2,0)+\dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}P(1,2)P(1,1)^2P(1,0)+P(1,1)^4 \\ & = 4\left(\dfrac{5}{2\cdot 6^4}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3+12\left(\dfrac{5}{2\cdot 6^3}\right)\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+6\left(\dfrac{5}{72}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+12\left(\dfrac{5}{72}\right)\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)^4 \\ & = \dfrac{865}{6912}\end{align*}$$

Essentially, what I am calculating is the probability of the following:

Only one die hits, but four times

2 dice have hits, one rolls 3 hits one rolls 1 hit

2 dice hit, both roll 2 hits

3 dice hit, one rolls 2 hits, two others roll 1 hit each

4 dice hit, one hit each

$$P(4,3) = \dbinom{4}{1}\left(\dfrac{5}{2\cdot 6^3}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3 + \dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\left(\dfrac{5}{72}\right)\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dbinom{4}{3}\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \dfrac{205}{864}$$

$$P(4,2) = \dbinom{4}{1}\left(\dfrac{5}{72}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3+\dbinom{4}{2}\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{85}{288}$$

$$P(4,5^+) = \dfrac{55}{768}$$

Edit: How to build an Excel spreadsheet to perform these calculations:

```
On Sheet1 - Probability of getting exact number of hits:
  Cell C1: Number of Dice
  Cell C2: 0
  Cell D2: 1
  Cell E2: 2
  .
  .
  .
  Cell M2: 10 (go as high as you like)
  .
  .
  .

  Cell A3: Number of Hits
  Cell B3: 0
  Cell B4: 1
  .
  .
  .
  Cell B13: 10 (go as high as you like)
  .
  .
  .

  Cell C3: =POWER(0.5,C2)
Copy this cell and paste formula to all cells C3:M3

  Set Cells C4:C13 to 0
  Cell D4: =5/(2*POWER(6,B4))
Copy this cell and paste formula to all cells D4:D13

  Cell E4: =E2*$D4*POWER(0.5,D2))
Copy this cell and paste formula to all cells E4:M4

  Cell E5: =SUMPRODUCT($D$3:$D5,N(OFFSET(D5,ROW(D$3)-ROW(D$3:D5),0)))
Copy this cell and paste formula to all cells E5:M13

At this point, you should have a table filled out with all probabilities for getting the exact number of hits (0 to 10) on any number of dice (0 to 10).

Rename the spreadsheet: NumberHitsCalculator (or whatever else you want to name it, but I am using this name below).

Add a new worksheet. I called it ThresholdCalculator.
Copy everything from NumberHitsCalculator to get the same general layout. Change cell A3 to: Minimum Number of Hits

Change cell C3:M3 to be 1 across the board (you will always get at least zero hits).

  Cell ThresholdCalculator!D4: =D3-NumberHitsCalculator!D3
Copy this cell and paste formula to all cells: ThresholdCalculator!D4:M13

This will give you all of the probabilities of hitting specific thresholds given the number of dice. Examples we have already gone over, like P(4,2+) gives 0.729167 as expected. P(4,5+) gives 0.071615 as expected, as well.
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I have a lot of questions. First, if I want to look at rolling 4 dice to get 5 successes, I use P(4,5+). Is that correct? How do I begin to break that down into a formula for an Excel doc or Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: It is not straightforward like that. Excel would likely require a macro to calculate efficiently. Google spreadsheet would probably not work at all. I can probably write up a macro to do this. R would likely be the easiest language to write it, but it should work in Excel, as well.

Comment: Awesome. I just need it for Google spreadsheet. Thanks! This explanation is really fantastic.

Comment: I doubt that a Google spreadsheet can handle macros the same way Excel can. This really is not easy to calculate outside of a statistics language. I am not sure what I could do in Google Sheets.

Comment: OK, let's go with Excel and I'll see if I can translate that. So, for 4 dice with 1 hit, the probability is around 90% and 2 hits on 4 dice is around 66-68%, right? Then, as above, to get 5 hits on 4 dice, we are looking at 55/768 or 7%, right?

Comment: Here is another way of calculating it. $$P(n,h^+) = P(n,(h-1)^+)-P(n,h-1)$$  So, $$P(4,0^+) = 1$$ $$P(4,1^+) = P(4,0^+)-P(4,0) = 1-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4 = \dfrac{15}{16} = 93.75\%$$ $$P(4,2^+) = P(4,1^+)-P(4,1) = \dfrac{15}{16}-4\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3 = \dfrac{35}{48} \approx 72\%$$ $$P(4,3^+) = P(4,2^+)-P(4,2) = \dfrac{35}{48} - 4\left(\dfrac{5}{72}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3 - 6\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{125}{288} \approx 43.4\%$$ Etc.

Comment: Gimme a day or two to come up with a solution for you. I might be able to do it with Google Sheets as I keep thinking about it. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Those numbers seem a little high. 72% of getting 2 hits on 4 dice? 35/48 seems off from what I have read on other sites. The other sites indicated it should be around 66-68%.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I guess I think the other sites are wrong? I am fairly confident in my answer.

Comment: I just ran an experiment where I had Excel simulate rolling four dice and seeing how many "hits" it gets. Out of 2000 rolls of four dice, 1430 had at least 2 hits (71.5%). This was just one experiment, but it seems legit. I'll update my answer with the code.

Comment: Oh, maybe the other sites you are looking at limit the number of extra hits you can get. There are some dice systems where if you roll a six, you get to roll one extra time, but you cannot keep rolling ad infinitum. My answers all assume you can keep rolling until you no longer get a six. That is a very different problem than if you only get to roll one additional time.

Comment: You can keep rolling on 6s, yes. But I would think that would increase your probability of success. I understand that 2 hits on 4 dice is not 50% or 1/2, but I would expect it would be closer to 50% than 70%. For each of the 4 dice we have 1/2 to hit or miss times permutations of two hits.

Comment: Suppose there were no explosions. We were just looking for the probability of getting two or more successes on four dice. That would be:  $$\dfrac{11}{16} \approx 68.75\%$$ However, the probability of getting exactly 2 successes on four dice is much lower! $$\dfrac{6}{16} \approx 37.5\%$$

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I think I get it now. Because we can reroll the 6s, we do in fact have slightly better odds than the 68% that I read on those sites. They were not accounting for the rerolls. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated with instructions to build an Excel spreadsheet. I could not figure out the formula for Google Sheets (I am not sure how to reverse an array in Google Sheets as part of a SUMPRODUCT formula).

Comment: This is working great. Finally, if I want to add a third sheet that displays the standard odds without the exploding dice, what formulas do I use? For example, just the standard 4 dice, 2 hit, 68%.

Comment: That's actually much easier. That is just the standard binomial formula. If a die hits with probability $p$, the probability of exactly $h$ hits on $n$ dice is given by $$\dbinom{n}{h}p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$$ If $p=\dfrac{1}{2}$, this formula becomes $$\dbinom{n}{h}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$ In Excel, assuming the number of dice is on C2:M2 and the number of hits is on B3:B13 (as above), then the formula for C3 would be $$\text{=COMBIN(C\$2,\$B3)*POWER(0.5,C\$2)}$$ This would create the equivalent of the first spreadsheet.

Comment: Then, if you want the probability of "at least" $h$ hits on $n$ dice, You would want the exact same formula as the ThresholdCalculator worksheet. You would want formula similar to the ThresholdCalculator worksheet.

Comment: But the Threshold calculator factors in the possibility of exploding dice. For the third sheet, I would also like the minimum threshold without re-rolls too. So, at least 2 hits on 4 dice = 68%.

Comment: Correct, so you would need a third sheet that does not calculate exploding dice, then the threshold worksheet would be exactly the same, but pointing to the new sheet instead of the exploding dice calculations. I just gave you the formula for the non-exploding dice calculations. Then, the threshold calculations are exactly the same.

Comment: To avoid the #Num error that occurs when $h>n$, use the formula $$\text{=IFERROR(COMBIN(C\$2,\$B3)*POWER(0.5,C\$2),0)}$$ in cell C3 on a new sheet (let's call the sheet NumHitsCalc2). Then, copy that cell and paste the formula to C3:M13. Then, create ThresholdCalculator2. Copy ThresholdCalculator (so all the formulas are currently the same). Now, in cell D4, change the formula to $$\text{=D3-NumHitsCalc2!D3}$$ Copy that cell, and paste the formula to D4:M13.